# Im trying to have a network policy which has egress to two other pods and a ip, which is a windows server

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

In gke cluster have a pod (hello) in default namespace, which acts like a client and connects to a server; installed in a windows vm present outside of cluster. Once connection is established between the client pod and server on windows vm; the pod receives transactions from server to the pod. In my policy I have given both egress and ingress rules. Strangely the even after giving wrong CIDR , the pod still receives traffic from windows vm. Hello app pod service is a loadbalancer type, which has external
node IP.
Expected result is when given wrong ip the connection should be denied, but I can still get transactions from server present on windows VM, even when i gave wrong ip in cidrblock.

here is my network policy.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: hello-network-policy  
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
      namespace: default
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - from:
     - ipBlock:
         cidr: 10.2.0.6/32 # ip of windows vm present outside of cluster
  egress:
    - to:
       - ipBlock:
           cidr: 10.7.0.3/32 # ip of db present outside of cluster
      ports:
        - port: 5432
    - to:
       - ipBlock:
           cidr: 10.2.0.6/32 # pod to connect to the windows
    - to:
      - namespaceSelector:
          matchLabels:
            name: kube-system
      ports:
        - port: 53
          protocol: UDP
    - to:
      - podSelector:
          matchLabels:
            app: activemq
    - to:
      - podSelector:
           matchLabels:
             app: rabbitmq
```

Comment: How is connection established? From pod to VM or from VM to pod? This is important here

Comment: Also could you please share following: cluster version, node types, if `istio` or other service mesh installed? Ideally to share pod and service yamls so it will be reproducible example

Comment: I might have an idea why it doesn't work for you. Can you please run this command `gcloud container clusters describe CLUSTER-NAME --zone ZONE | grep -A2 "networkPolicy:"` and let me know if it's enabled (you can add this to your question, because it's important)

Comment: Yes, the network policy is enabled, and still this problem persists. I have calico cni in cluster, It is a private cluster. istio is not enabled in that namespace. Connection is from the pod to the vm. I can even see the logs of the pod that says "CLIENT IS TRYING TO CONNECT THE 10.0.0.0:8808. And i can still get traffic even when i gave wrong cidr in policy.

Comment: @ragz24 Have you managed to move it forward?

Comment: no. i could not move it forward. currently looking at how traffic is coming to pod

Comment: @ragz24 Please try to run [this example from GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/network-policy) to make sure that network policies are applied and work. If so, then I'll need to have yaml manifests to reproduce your environment as close as possible.